# How to stop automatic recalculation in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

In the excel sheet pictured below I would like the recalculation to stop  for the top portion from Row 1-5. And what I mean with recalculation is that for example cell M2, H4, S4 have the today() formula and every time I open it it recalculates. I would like for it to calculate once and once I save as to not recalculate again once opened again. Any suggestions? I have tried

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: check, if your workbook_open event is fired. Or check application.calculation value on your sheet

Comment: If you want the rest of the sheet to calculate normally, you will have to write a Macro into the BeforeSave event, that writes the Today() value into the cells as values.

Comment: instead of turning automatic calculation on and off, replace you TODAY() formula with a fixed date.  Add a button that will update the fixed date when you press it.  That way it will only update the information to today when you are ready for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, setting `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the time of `Workbook_Open` may not always assure you the desired result as there is a possibility that the Excel might be in `xlCalculationAutomatic` while opening your file.

So the workaround is, open `Excel` and set calculation to manual either in VBE or through menus and then open your file.
**In VBE**, type `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` in immediate window then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then open your file.
**In Excel**, for 2007 version, click on `Formula Menu`, go to `Calculation Group`,  in `Calculation Options` select `Automatic/Manual`. For older versions, `Tools > Options > Calculation`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the reputation to post a comment to ask a clarifying question, so I will post an answer instead (making an assumption about what your answer would be).

As long as you never want those cells to recalculate (and don't mind losing the formula), the easiest solution would be to convert them to values.

simple macro to achieve this for first 5 rows:

```
sub ConvertToValues()
Dim rngToValues as Range
set rngToValues = YourSheet.UsedRange.Rows("1:5").EntireRow
rngToValues.Value = rngToValues.Value
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest evaluating the function in VBA on events you want.

If you want TODAY function to calculate on your request, I would create a button with a macro that reevaluates TODAY.

How I would implement this depends on if you want/need to have the cell as a formula. 
If it is enough to have the calculated value, you can calculate in VBA and set the value to the cells you want.
If you want to have a formula and keep the last evaluated TODAY value, you can set the formula to the cell.
`Range("M2").Formula = Date() & "other formula part"`

The easiest solution is to set todays value in some cell, in VBA

```
Sub Macro1 ()

    Range("A5").Value = Date()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add the below subroutine under `Workbook_Open` in `PERSONAL.XLSB` (to be saved at `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART`) so that it gets loaded whenever Excel application is launched.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False 
End Sub
```

While `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` will set the calculation mode to `Manual` (3rd Option in the below screenshot), `Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False` will untick the checkbox to `Recalculate workbook before saving`

[image]